# Como resolver erro NullPointerException no android studio 2.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

estou com o android studio 2.3, e desde que atualizei ele vem dando esse erro:[image: erro de NullPointerException:]

gostaria de saber como se revolver isso. O android studio não é afetado...continua trabalhando normal, mas isso é muito chato..esse erro sempre vem durando os meus trabalhos...queria saber como se resolve isso.

Valeu pra quem ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Na pasta raiz do seu projeto, exclua a pasta .gradle.

```
C:\Usuario\VipinSaini\AndroidStudioProjects\MeuProjeto\.gradle (tem uma barra antes de .gradle mas não aparece aqui - bug)
```

em seguida, reinicie o Android Studio